# Understanding Django (from source code): attributes of field via models.CharField and forms.CharField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to understand how `django.db.models` and `django.forms` work together on a `field`.

Consider this example:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model)
  Telefon1 = models.CharField('Telefon', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

displays via `generic.edit.FormView` in `views` the form field in HTML correctly with the default value 'Telefon'. In order to turn off autocomplete-functionality I add the following:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.ModelsForm):
  Telefon1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
```

The field then is correctly rendered with `automplete:off`. But the name of the field falls back to the `models` name: `Telefon1`

So **question 1**: How do I make sure that the default name defined in `models` is being passed through or do I have to re-define the name with `forms.CharField(widget=...`?
**Question 2**: How can I find the answer reading the source code? I started by reading `site-packages\django\forms\widget.py` which either doesn't include the answer or I did not understand.

*I would like to learn and understand Django via source code since the tutorial and documentation doesn't always work for me (especially in this case).*

Comment: Reading the source code is not a good way to learn a framework. Django has some of the best documentation in the open-source world, plus a whole internet full of third-party tutorials; you should start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about `django.db.models.Field` and `django.forms.Field` are exactly two different machines. But still in real life we need forms that supposedly need to map the models. To accomplish that, django has provided us with the concept of django modelforms which we make by passing name of the model.

By default django modelforms shows same name as that of django models but in case you need to override the name, you can by overriding `__init()` in django modelforms as also specified in [here](http://www.pydanny.com/overloading-form-fields.html) to further clarify your understanding.

The code base of django is already developed and is still being developed to the extent of optimization. The point of learning is deeply admired but falling down into complexities is just waste of effectiveness and beats the purpose of being called as a Rapid Application Development Technology.

Whatever is given in official docs is self sufficient and deep enough to help you gain a great understanding. Ths only best way to learn a framework is to learn its error messages then you will automatically be the master of intricacies of this framework.